# Broadcom driver for Solaris

Tags: drivers, solaris, broadcom

I just installed Solaris 11.3 on the laptop. This laptop have Broadcom BCM4312 WiFi card.

It looks like the install does not have a driver for this card just like 11.1 version.

I have a Linux installed on this same machine (Gentoo) and this OS does have a driver.

Is it possible to get the driver for this card somewhere? Maybe broadcom.com? Failing that is it possible to use Linux driver inside Solaris?

On the kind of related side - I tried to connect a wire and run Driver Manager, but it does not want to finish. All controls are  still disabled. Any idea?

Thank you for any pointers you can provide.

Comment: WLAN drivers which are supplied with Solaris are listed here: http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/catalog.shtml under `driver/network/wlan` prefix. It appears that none of them supports Broadcom

Comment: @myaut, is it possible to run Linux driver under Solaris?

Comment: no. Kernels have completely different APIs

Comment: @myaut, is there a list of wireless cards that have driver available for Solaris 11.3? preferably  USB ones?

Comment: @Igor - see the [Solaris Hardware Compatibility List website](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/index.html).

Comment: Just run Solaris *inside* your Linux, using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). I do that and it is surprisingly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

@Igor, your best bet is to check out the HCL, but as Solaris is intended as a server operating system, it's unlikely that many wireless chipsets are going to be certified unless they carried over from OpenSolaris.

As a work around, you could try running Linux in a VM and using that as a proxy or router to access the internet from the global.  Or manually connect to a wireless repeater that you get instead of a USB wireless card?